# Cocoa: font downloaded from the web

Tags: cocoa, macos, fonts, metadata, message

I'm coding an app that needs a font that is not available on the system. I got the font from the web, but every time I launch the app, I get this message:

http://twitpic.com/3h4nj9

I cannot ship an app with this kind of message. I believe it's some metadata on the font file. Does anyone knows how can I solve that problem?

Thanks!

Answer (score 5):

This is a security feature of the OS. You should not be trying to "solve" it.

I'd suggest obtaining a license for the font and bundling the file as a resource in your app. Or do without.

[EDIT]: I misunderstood. Since it's a file you're including in your bundle, you want to clear the com.apple.quarantine metadata from the file. Use the command

```
xattr -d com.apple.quarantine my_font_file.otf
```

You probably also want to get rid of the com.apple.metadata:kMDItemWhereFroms metadata as well.

You can just use

```
xattr my_font_file.otf
```

to get a list of all the extended attributes that the OS is keeping on the file. Delete as appropriate (with the -d flag).

Comment: But I'm including the font on my app bundle.

Comment: It's a shareware font: http://www.dafont.com/ds-digital.font (Comes with a readme giving the license.)

Comment: My apologies: I misunderstood your original issue. I've edited my answer to be a bit more helpful.